# Signing in to Sharepoint 2013 using Identity server 3 fails due to certificate validation issue

Tags: sharepoint-2013, identityserver3

I am configuring a SharePoint 2013 web application to use Identiy server 3 as an identity provider, the configuration is done successfully and identiy server is added as a trusted identity token issuer to SharePoint, I have used identity server 3 Test Certificate as the signing certificate for SharePoint but every time, the redirect url gives an error occurred, this is the error in the log

An operation failed because the following certificate has validation errors:  Subject Name: CN=idsrv3test Issuer Name: CN=DevRoot Thumbprint: Errors:   PartialChain: A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.  RevocationStatusUnknown: The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.  OfflineRevocation: The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint needs to have the entire certificate chain, right up to the root, added as a `SPTrustedRootAuthority`.

In the "Import a token signing certificate by using Windows PowerShell" section of the [Configure SAML-based claims authentication with AD FS in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305235.aspx#Anchor_4) article:

> This step must be repeated for every token signing certificate in the chain until the root certification authority is reached.

So you can either get the root certificate of the IdentityServer test certificate, which is called [DevRoot](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Certificates/DevRoot.cer) or [create your own self-signed certificate](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Windows/Yet-Another-MakeCert-Tutorial) for token signing.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that really helped me a lot!